# R Panel Data - Get Common Variables between Current and All Consecutive Waves

Tags: r, tidyverse, panel-data, data-wrangling

we currently working in a hobby project with huge panel data (with a lot of waves, i.e., measurement timepoints), which can be quite challenging. To get an overview, one idea was to find variables that are common from the current to all consecutive waves.

Explanation with an example:

```
Wave 1: Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4    
Wave 2: Var1, Var2, Var4, Var5   
Wave 3: Var1, Var5, Var6, Var7
```

Here *Wave 1*: has Var1 and Var2 in common with *Wave2*, and only Var1 with *Wave3*. *Wave2* has in common with *Wave3*: Var1 and Var5

**Desired output**

A tibble (or data.frame) that shows in the rows the wave of interest, and in the column for each consecutive wave which variables are in common.

| Starting | Wave1 | Wave2 | Wave3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wave1 | - | Var1, Var2 | Var1 |
| Wave2 | - | - | Var1, Var5 |
| Wave3 | - | - | - |

Simulation data:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)
wave1 <- tibble(
  id = seq_along(1:100),
  a = runif(100, 0, 100),
  o = runif(100, 0, 100),
  x = runif(100, 0, 100),
  y = runif(100, 0, 100),
  z = runif(100, 0, 100)
)
# In wave2 some observations drop out & some new observations are added
wave2 <- tibble(
  id = seq_along(1:150),
  a = runif(150, 0, 100),
  b = runif(150, 0, 100),
  c = runif(150, 0, 100),
  d = runif(150, 0, 100),
  e = runif(150, 0, 100),
  x = runif(150, 0, 100),
  y = runif(150, 0, 100)
)
# Simulation of Dropout
wave2 %>%
  filter(!id %in% sample(1:150, 23)) -> wave2

# Same with Wave 3
wave3 <- tibble(
  id = c(wave2 %>% pull(id),151:200),
  a = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  b = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  c = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  
  i = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  j = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  k = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  l = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  
  x = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100),
  z = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100)
)
# Simulation of Dropout
wave3 %>%
  filter(!id %in% sample(1:200, 33)) -> wave3

# Same with Wave 4
wave4 <- tibble(
  id = c(wave3 %>% pull(id),201:300),
  a = runif(nrow(wave3) + 100, 0, 100),
  c = runif(nrow(wave3) + 100, 0, 100),
  
  i = runif(nrow(wave3) + 100, 0, 100),
  j = runif(nrow(wave3) + 100, 0, 100),
  l = runif(nrow(wave3) + 100, 0, 100),
  
  z = runif(nrow(wave3) + 100, 0, 100)
)

# Simulation of Dropout in Wave 4
wave4 %>%
  filter(!id %in% sample(1:200, 41)) -> wave4
```

In the simulated data e.g. the Variable `a` would be present in all waves.

**What I got so far**

Iterate with a for-loop over the names of the waves (obtained by `ls` and a regex-pattern), get the current position and the next one up, get the data from the environment with `get` and read out the colnames. With `intersect` get the common column names between the current (in terms of the for loop) and the next wave. Save everything to a tibble (that was initialized empty).

And finally group_by and summarise to get everything in one column

```
##### Get Common Variables between all waves
# Get names of Tibbles (data) from environment
names_waves <- ls(pattern = "wave\\d+") %>% str_sort(numeric = TRUE)
waves_lagged_common2 <- tibble(wave = character(),common_vars = character())
for (wave in names_waves) {
  cur_pos <- names_waves %>% match(x = wave)
  print(cur_pos)
  if (cur_pos != length(names_waves)) {
    cur_wave_names <- get(wave) %>% names()
    next_wave_names <- get(names_waves[cur_pos + 1]) %>% names()
    intersect(cur_wave_names,next_wave_names) -> common_vars
    waves_lagged_common2 <- waves_lagged_common2 %>% add_row(wave = wave, common_vars = common_vars)
  }
}
# Merge the rows with group_by and summarise
waves_lagged_common2 %>% 
  group_by(wave) %>% 
  summarize(common_vars = paste(common_vars, collapse = ", "))
```

Current output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  wave  common_vars         
  <chr> <chr>               
1 wave1 id, a, x, y         
2 wave2 id, a, b, c, x      
3 wave3 id, a, c, i, j, l, z
```

**Further efforts to achieve desired output**

Implement an additional for-loop inside the for-loop to get for the current wave (`cur_pos`) all consecutive waves. And work with `add_row`

```
common_vars_matrix <- tibble(Wave = names_waves) %>%
  column_to_rownames("Wave")
for (wave in names_waves) {
  cur_pos <- names_waves %>% match(x = wave)
  print(cur_pos)
  if (cur_pos != length(names_waves)) {
    cur_wave_names <- get(wave) %>% names()
    next_row_to_add <- c()
    for (next_wave in names_waves[cur_pos+1:length(names_waves)]) {
      next_wave_names <- get(next_wave) %>% names()
      intersect(cur_wave_names,next_wave_names) -> common_vars
      print(next_wave)
      # print(common_vars)
      next_row_to_add <- c(next_row_to_add,common_vars)
      print(next_row_to_add)
    }
  }
}
```

However all these for-loops feel not really tidy.

Also I am running into out of index operators. At this point I am wondering if it is a good idea at all to use loops and "automate" the process, or if it would be just easier / more readable to work like this

```
wave1 %>% names -> names_wave1
wave2 %>% names -> names_wave2
wave3 %>% names -> names_wave3
wave4 %>% names -> names_wave4

common_1_2 <- intersect(names_wave1,names_wave2)
common_1_3 <- intersect(names_wave1,names_wave3)
common_1_4 <- intersect(names_wave1,names_wave4)

common_vars_matrix <- tibble(wave2=paste(common_1_2,collapse=","),
                             wave3=paste(common_1_3, collapse=","),
                             wave4=paste(common_1_4, collapse=","))

common_2_3 <- intersect(names_wave2,names_wave3)
common_2_4 <- intersect(names_wave2,names_wave4)

common_vars_matrix <- common_vars_matrix %>% add_row(wave2="-",
                               wave3=paste(common_2_3, collapse=","),
                               wave4=paste(common_2_4, collapse=","))
# And so forth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your desired output, this seems to give you what you want.

```
# Initialize a data frame with row names of your waves
df <- data.frame(row.names = ls(pattern = "wave"))

# Add in the dashes that you want
for (row in rownames(df)) {
  df[, row] = "-"
}

# Outer loop will loop through rows
for (row in rownames(df)) {
  # Get the data frame corresponding to that row
  row_df <- get(row)
  # Inner loop will loop through the columns
  for (col in colnames(df)) {
    # Get the data frame corresponding to the column
    col_df <- get(col)
    # If they are the same (ex. wave1/ wave1), leave it alone
    if (row != col) {
      # Find which column names are in both
      var_both <- colnames(row_df)[which(colnames(row_df) %in% colnames(col_df))]
      # Concatenate and add the value as a string at the intersection
      df[row, col] <- paste(var_both, collapse = ", ")
    }
  }
}
```

But if you have many data frames this may not be the most efficient performance-wise since it contains a nested loop (ie. O(n<sup>2</sup>)).

Regardless, the output is:

```
            wave1          wave2                wave3                wave4
wave1           -    id, a, x, y          id, a, x, z             id, a, z
wave2 id, a, x, y              -       id, a, b, c, x             id, a, c
wave3 id, a, x, z id, a, b, c, x                    - id, a, c, i, j, l, z
wave4    id, a, z       id, a, c id, a, c, i, j, l, z                    -
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes I feel like I try to force a tidyverse solution when base R can be the solution. Gonna test this out tomorrow and accept it if it works  (which just from the look at the code, should be the case).